# Executing a Redshift procedure through AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have created Stored procedures on Redshift and need to orchestrate it. The SP contains the DML statements for SCD creation and is limited to Redshift.

Is there a way on AWS to run the SP on Redshift through Glue or any other AWS services?

As we do not have triggers on RS I am exploring other options. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try making use of preactions/Postactions. Preactions/Postactions allow you to execute sql commands before/after your dynamic frames processes data. You can provide a list of semi-colon delimited commands, for example just normal sql commands, you could try call the procedures using the same approach:

```
datasink5 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = prod_dynamicframe, catalog_connection = "my_rdshft", connection_options = {"preactions":"delete from dw.product_dim where sku in ('xxxxx,'bbbb');","dbtable": "dw.product_dim", "database": "DWBI","postactions":"truncate table ld_stg.ld_product_tbl;"}, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "datasink5")
```

[This](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sql-commands-redshift-glue-job/) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you can try is preactions and postactions as mentioned by @Eman, I haven't tried it .

But I used psycopg2 to trigger the stored procedure on redshift.
Just zip the package and pass to glue.

Establish a jdbc connection

and use `callproc()` function to call the stored procedure.

Find its usage https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html